# ODBC Query to SQL Need help converting date

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, odbc, ssrs-2012

I am new to SQL using an OBDC connection. For a VERY basic SQL statement, I am unable to get a date parameter to work. I'm not sure if its the format.

Example code:

```
SELECT ACCOUNT.ACCOUNT_NUM, ACCOUNT.ACCOUNT_OPEN_DATE
FROM ACCOUNT ACCOUNT
WHERE (ACCOUNT.ACCOUNT_OPEN_DATE = ?)
```

The `?` being the date parameter. In excel we just point this `?` to a cell that contains a value of `=TODAY()`

So in SSRS 2012, in the parameters, I need to make it so that `=TODAY()` converts to the format compatible with ODBC which is in the format of `{d 'yyyy-mm-dd'}`

How would I accomplish this? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equivalent is GETDATE().  See below:

```
SELECT ACCOUNT.ACCOUNT_NUM 
       ,ACCOUNT.ACCOUNT_OPEN_DATE
FROM ACCOUNT ACCOUNT
WHERE (ACCOUNT.ACCOUNT_OPEN_DATE GETDATE())
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: Very glad to help, brodimaggio12